# Python: How do I pass a file path as parameter to a function without defining it as a string before putting it into the function?

Tags: python, filepath, rawstring

My end goal is to have a user copy and paste a file path into a PySimpleGUI without having to put quotes around the file path.

Here is the a brief summary of the function:

```
def fun1(filepath):
normal = os.path.normpath(filepath)
raw_data = pd.read_csv(normal)
# more code
return X_Angle, Y_Angle
```

Then here is the function implemented into PySimpleGui

```
 sg.theme('BluePurple')

layout = [[sg.Text('paste filepath'), sg.Text(size=(15,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Input(key='-IN-'), sg.Text(size=(15,1), justification='center'), sg.FileBrowse()],
          [sg.Text(key='-BING-'), sg.Text(size=(2,1)), sg.Text('(X_Angle, Y_Angle)')],
          [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Pattern 2B', layout)

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Show':
        window['-BING-'].update(fun1(values['-IN-']))
        
      
        # Update the "output" text element to be the value of "input" element
       
    

window.close
```

The error I get is "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'"
Which I believe is just do to the backslashes in the file path. The function works fine when I copy and paste the filepath into the function with quotes around it and r in front of it so its read as a raw string. However, my goal is to make this so the user can just copy and go.

Comment: For instance, if I run: 
fun1(r'C:\Users\Spencer.Cody\sdjfnsaijgnisf.csv')
it runs great because of the r in front of the filepath. I would like to just be able to have the function accept the path without the r nor the ' '

Comment: Open the Python interpreter and try `print('Hello\nWorld')` and see the `\n` becomes a newline. Now try `print(input('Type Something: '))` and when prompted, enter `Hello\nWorld`. The `\n` does not become a newline. Quotes around text and backslashes that the programmer enters in code are there for the Python interpreter to tell text from the rest of your code. They are different to things the user enters at runtime, which are taken literally, not interpreted.

Comment: A good permission denied message says `"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\windows'"`. Yours has a `"."` as the path. In the function, try to print the filepath like `printf(filepath)` or show it in a popup message and see what it is getting. You can recreate that error by running `open('.')` in the interactive prompt.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you actually have it, since indentation is crucial in Python. What you show would give syntax errors. Anyway, I can't understand the question as asked, and I think it's because the way you're asking it is based on some misconceptions.

Comment: Putting quotes around *user input* doesn't "define it as a string"; it just means that the user's input now has a quote symbol at the beginning and end - unless there is something in your program that *deliberately attempts to interpret that input as Python code* or equivalent. Regardless, the way forward from here is to try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't possibly analyze this independently - for example: what's `sg`?

Comment: "if I run: fun1(r'C:\Users\Spencer.Cody\sdjfnsaijgnisf.csv') it runs great because of the r in front of the filepath" Yes, in that case you need the r and the quotation marks because that text is **part of your code**, so that's how you communicate in Python that that part is the string (rather than variable names or expressions or some other thing). But here, the **code** says `fun1(values['-IN-'])`, to mean that the string *that is contained in the dictionary* will be used. You don't need quotes because you aren't writing the string in your code. It came from outside.

Comment: It seems like you are generally confused because you got an error and made a completely wrong assumption about the cause of the error. You would understand the error message better if you tried to *read* it first. It says: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'`. Notice how, after saying what kind of error it is, there is a string - in quotation marks, because Python wants you to understand that it's showing you a string and that isn't part of its own message - that is written as `'.'`?. That means it *contains* just `.`. That is the path that your program tries to use.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I appreciate the responses. I definitely think I am combing the two issues I have and assuming they both have the same solution.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I added the print line in the function and got 
"Show {'-IN-': '', 'Browse': 'C:/Users/Spencer.Cody/211215-215354-cell-imager-quality.csv'}" 
which I think shows that the I should have the browser key going into the function not the -IN- key.  I had wrongly assumed that any thing that appeared in the GUI box was going to be fed into the function.